# Sorting a tuple by variable

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, collections, tuples

i am doing the following activity:
The objective is to develop a program to manage a list of members of 
in a competition of long jump. The number of places available is 15. 
Their data will be introduced in the same order in which the athletes 
enroll. 
Design a program that shows the following options:

1 – Register a participant

2 – List all the participant’s data

3 – List all the participant’s data by mark

4 – Quit
If 1 is selected, data of one of the participants will be introduced: 
Name, best mark in 2012, best mark in 2011 and best mark in 2010.

If 2 is selected, we have to list all participant’s data ordered by dorsal 
number (the order they’ve enrolled)

If 3 is selected, we have to list all participant’s data ordered by 2012 
mark, from greater to smaller.

After processing each option, the main menu must be shown again, 
till the option 4 is selected, quitting the program.

I am stuck on ordering the data by mark, this is my program, any idea please?

```
package prc;

import epsa.Cio;

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.List;

public class Rrc2

{

    public static void main(String[] args)


    {

        int n=0;
        Tupla participants[]= new Tupla[15];
        while(true){    

        Cio.println("Choose what you would like to do");
        Cio.println("Type 1 to:Register a participant");
        Cio.println("Type 2 to:List all the participant's data");
        Cio.println("Type 3 to:List all the participants data by mark");
        Cio.println("Type 4 to:Quit");
    int i;

    i = Cio.readInt();

switch(i)
{
case 1:

    participants[n]= new Tupla();
    Cio.println("Insert dorsal number");
    participants[n].number = Cio.readInt();
    Cio.println("Insert participants name");
    participants[n].name = Cio.readString();
    Cio.println("Insert participants best mark for the year 2012");
    participants[n].bestMark2012 = Cio.readDouble(); 
    Cio.println("Insert participants best mark for the year 2011");
    participants[n].bestMark2011 = Cio.readDouble();
    Cio.println("Insert participants best mark for the year 2010");
    participants[n].bestMark2010 = Cio.readDouble();
    n++;



    break;

case 2:
    int t;

    for(t=0;t<15&&t<n;t++){ 

        Cio.println("name: " + participants[t].name);
        Cio.println("Dorsal number: " + participants[t].number);
        Cio.println("Best Mark 2012: " + participants[t].bestMark2012);
        Cio.println("Best Mark 2011: " + participants[t].bestMark2011);
        Cio.println("Best Mark 2010: " + participants[t].bestMark2010);
        Cio.println("//////////////////////////////////////////////////");
    }



    break;

case 3:

Collections.sort(participants);


break;

case 4:System.exit(0); 
break; 


default: 
    Cio.println("Not valid");

    break;


}
Cio.println("Press enter to continue");
Cio.readString();
}

    }
}
```

Comment: What is a `prc.Tupla` object?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement `java.util.Comparator<Tupla>` and pass that into your call to `Collections.sort()`  (and use a `java.util.List` instead of an array)

```
Collections.sort(participants, new TuplaComparator());
```

You need to implement (write the class yourself) for `TuplaComparator`. It should implement the interface `java.util.Comparator<Tupla>`. (See javadocs.)

The variable `participants` should be an `ArrayList` rather than a simple array for `Collections.sort()` to work.

That's plenty of clues to be getting on with. I'm not going to reproduce your entire (homework?) program code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still dont understand your answer, could you please modify my program please? Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you added line numbers to your program.